# A-Frame How to rotate and zoom in and zoom out using obj/mtl file inside scene

Tags: zooming, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

i 've been searching for a while to do 3 particular things ..
1- do rotation around the obj smoothly and what is the best practice for dis
2- zoom in and zoom out on the obj/mtl loaded inside the a-scene
3- how to display the obj/mtl file only when it detects a floor or surface or anything but not camera!

what i've tried?
1- all links and problems here on StackOverFlow and A-frame documentation as well
2- this [zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58748998/how-to-zoom-a-frame-videosphere)
3- this [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459356/a-frame-zoom-on-wheel-scroll)

what i want to achieve ..
1- zoom in out on web and mobile by clicking or touching
2- do the right way to rotate an object
this is my code `

```
 <script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('rotation-reader', {
  tick: (function () {
    var position = new THREE.Vector3();
    var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

    return function () {
      this.el.object3D.getWorldPosition(position);
      this.el.object3D.getWorldQuaternion(quaternion);
    };
  })()
});
```

```
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('zoom-controls', {
    schema: {
      min: {
        type: "number",
        default: 5
       },
     max: {
        type: "number",
        default: 120
       }
       },
       init: function () {
          let self = this;
    let sceneEl = document.querySelector("a-scene");
    self.camera = sceneEl.querySelector("#camera");
    console.log('min: ', self.data.min);
    console.log('max: ', self.data.max);
    window.addEventListener("click", event => {
      let amount = Math.sign(event.deltaY) * 5;
      let fov = Number(self.camera.getAttribute('camera').fov);
      let adjust = amount + fov;
      if (adjust < self.data.min) {
        adjust = self.data.min;
      }
      if (adjust > self.data.max) {
        adjust = self.data.max;
      }
      console.log('zoom: ', adjust);
      self.camera.setAttribute('camera', 'fov', adjust);
    });
  }
});
```

```
 <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<a-scene embedded arjs>
<!-- obj file  -->
<a-assets>
  <a-asset-item id="obj-Model" src="models/printing-press.obj"></a-asset-item>
  <a-asset-item id="obj-mtl" src="models/printing-press.mtl"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>

<!-- <a-animation attribute='scale' dur='500' direction='alternate' from='1 1 1' to='3 3 3' begin='click' repeat='1'>
   </a-animation> -->
    <a-entity id="camera" wasd-controls rotation-reader camera 
       look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true;"
       obj-model="obj: #obj-Model; mtl: #obj-mtl" zoom- 
      controls="min:5; max:140" fov="100" position="0 0 0"
      scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" rotation="0 0 0" 
      animation="property: 
      camera.zoom; dur=500; direction=alternate; from=1; to=2; 
      begin=click; repeat=1;
      easing:easeInOutQuad; loop: true; dir: alternate;">
</a-entity>

   <a-entity id="rig" position="0 0 11">
      <a-camera id="camera" look-controls="enabled:false"></a-camera>
      </a-entity>
   </a-scene>
 </body>
```

`

Comment: `when it detects a floor or surface or anything but not camera` - you mean in AR mode on mobile?

Comment: yes @PiotrAdamMilewski

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski do u have a solution for the first two parts ?

Comment: something like [this](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/ar/arjs_rotate_zoom.html) ?

Comment: something like [this](https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/manipulate-aframe)